# SQLite - Is there a better way to change the relative ordering of rows?

Tags: php, sqlite, pdo

I have a simple list of albums in a "collection of albums". I have an "album" table which has an "album_id", a "collection" table which has a "collection_id" and an "album_collection" table to join the two together so I can know which albums belong to a collection.

For each link in "album_collection" I also have an "ordering" column to specify the order in which the albums should be read. However I'm doing it **in reverse** so that I can just add at count + 1 instead of having to shift all the orders up by 1 on add.

Now, I can arbitrarily rearrange these albums graphically... now I just have to do it in the database as well. Here is my **working** solution using PDO in PHP, but I can tell it's a naive approach but I can't think of a different way to do it. How can I improve on this?

```
function rearrange_album_in_collection_order($collection_id, $album_id, $old_index, $new_index){

    if($old_index=== $new_index) return "same order so no change";

    $count = get_album_count($collection_id);
    if($count === 0){
        return "empty collection or incorrect id";
    }

    // this is because we're ordering forwards visually
    // but backwards in the database.
    $old = $count - $old_index + 1;
    $new = $count - $new_index + 1;

    $db = getDatabaseConnection();
    if($new_order > $old_order){

        $reorder = "UPDATE collections_albums 
                    SET ordering = ordering + 1 
                    WHERE collection_id=:cid 
                    AND ordering >= :new 
                    AND ordering < :old"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($reorder);

        $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $collection_id);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":old", $old);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":new", $new);

        $stmt->execute();

        $set = "UPDATE collections_albums 
                SET ordering=:new
                WHERE collection_id=:cid AND album_id=:aid"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($set);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":new", $new);
         $stmt->bindvalue(":aid", $album_id);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $collection_id);

        $stmt->execute();

    } else {
        $reorder = "UPDATE collections_albums 
                    SET ordering= ordering - 1 
                    WHERE collection_id=:cid 
                    AND ordering <= :new 
                    AND ordering > :old"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($reorder);

        $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $collection_id);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":old", $old);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":new", $new);

        $stmt->execute();

        $set = "UPDATE collections_albums 
                SET ordering=:new
                WHERE collection_id=:cid AND album_id=:aid"; 

        $stmt = $db->prepare($set);
        $stmt->bindvalue(":new", $new);
         $stmt->bindvalue(":aid", $album_id);
        $stmt->bindValue(":cid", $collection_id);

        $stmt->execute();
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I have posted this on code review instead?

Comment: Doing it in reverse is not necessary because you could just at well insert at `minimum - 1`.

Comment: The naive approach would be to update all records, one by one.